# which tense to use: present simple or past simple?

Tags: grammar, past-vs-present

In a situation, [for example] when the guy is continuously cheating and at the moment i say that sentence he is still cheating [/for example], should i say "he was cheating" or "he is cheating"?

There're 2 variants of that example sentence:

"i screamed at him because he was cheating"
or
"i screamed at him because he is cheating"

Let's say, for example, that i screamed at him 5 minutes ago. He began cheating 10 minutes ago and now he is still cheating. 
Which of these 2 variants should i use?

Comment: Consider *has been*

Comment: "It depends upon what the meaning of the word 'is' is". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_of_Bill_Clinton

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like just another "what do I call my cheating boyfriend/girlfriend" type of rant.

Comment: do as you want, but i actually wanted to get what i wanted to get. And why do you think that cheating is possible only in bed? The sentence about cheating is from the game.

Comment: your comment is way more off-topic and unlogic by the way. The sentence about cheating is an example. Why do you have to worry about it?

Comment: I wanted to say this after somebody asked me in the game about the reason i had yelled at the guy. And i didn't know what would be more correct. That's why i put here exactly what i wanted to say. Anyway, i'm really interested why you worry about examples this much.

Comment: You yelled at the guy, and you are asking what would be more correct...in what sense?

Comment: Cascabel, if you can't get the sense of my question you can read it 5 or more times. It's not about yelling or cheating. yelling + cheating is an example. If example about cheating somehow hurts you, then i gotta remind that it's not sexual cheating, but cheating in game. If "yelling" somehow hurts you too,  you can imagine that it's not yelling, but, for example, eating an apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"I screamed at him because he was cheating".**

The point is he was cheating at the time you screamed. We use the Past Continuous with the Past Simple to say that something happened in the middle of something else. Some other examples:

> I **called** the police when I **saw** that a stranger **was trying**
>   to unlock my neighbor's door.
>
> Someone **knocked** when I **was sleeping**.

By the way, "yell" might be better than "scream" in this context. If you **yell**, you shout loudly, usually because you are excited, **angry**, or in pain. When someone screams, they make a very loud, high-pitched cry, for example because they are in pain or are very frightened.

So, I suggest **"I yelled at him when I saw he was cheating."**

Comment: Ok, but what if i'd talk about somebody's nation/name/race, so that it is constant (would never be changed), should i still use past time? For example: "I looked at him because his name is/was Andrew "

Comment: @МаркПавлович In this case you are free to use "is" or "was". "Was" - because he was Andrew then, when you looked at him, and "is" - because he still is. BTW, not "time" but "tense". Tense is related to grammar, time isn't.